# Lagrangian mechanics, generalized coordinates, equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, potential, hamiltonian-formalism

Let $U(\vec{x}, \vec{v}) = -K \vec{A}(\vec{x})*\vec{v}$ be the generalized potential, where $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x} = \vec{v}$, $K$ is a constant and $\frac{\partial \vec{A}(\vec{x})}{\partial t} = 0$
Now I showed that $$F = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial U}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = K \vec{v} \times (rot\vec{A})\space \space (1)$$ 
From there I calculated the Lagrangian equation of a $m$ in this potential:
$$L = \frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}^2 - U$$
and the hamilton equation: 
$$H = \frac{(\vec{p}-K\vec{A})^2}{2m}$$
Is this correct? And from there I tried to calculate the equations of motion with $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$but I always get $0 = 0$, does anyone know why?

Kind Regards

EDIT:
 $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{dt} (mv+\frac{\partial U}{\partial v}) - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = F + \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial U}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = F - F = 0$
where the last conversion is true because of (1).

Comment: Yes, I know that, what is it explicitly? I could give you the answer, but I rather help you find the error so we can all learn.

Comment: ah ok, $\vec{p} = m\vec{v} + K\vec{A}$ so $\vec{v} = \frac{p-K\vec{A}}{m}$

Comment: Then the Euler-Lagrange equation will be $\dot p = \partial_x U$, I don't see how this cancles to $0=0$

Comment: if you plug it all in, it cancels each other out. Same with the equations of motions obtained from the lagrangian equation

Comment: @AngelJoaniquetTukiainen I will edit my post and add the calculation of the equations of motion from the lagarian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the zero identity because you are using the Equations of motion twice, one throught the Euler-Lagrange equations and the other time as with the definition of the force $F$.

Use only one, Newton law:

$$
\dot p = F = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial U}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = K \vec{v} \times (rot\vec{A})$$

or the Euler-Lagrange equations:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(p_i - k A_i\right) = \dot p - k \partial_jA_i\dot x^j = \partial_jU = -k\partial_jA_ix^i
$$

and you can see that both are the same equation, as you know, because you used it twice and got 0.

Comment: Does it mean anything special that you wrote that one indice as an exponent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: and on the first equations isn't the differential of the impulse already $F$ so that $m$ wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: True, and in the second one